# Pivot Access to SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table like this

```
Index  |  FeatureType  |  FeatureExists
1      |  BR           |  0
1      |  EI           |  NULL
1      |  RD           |  NULL
1      |  SEI          |  0
1      |  SNI          |  NULL
1      |  SSI          |  0
```

And I would like to transform it like the following :

```
Index | BR | EI   | RD   | SEI | SNI  | SSI
1     | 0  | NULL | NULL | 0   | NULL | 0
```

So there's the code I used in my Microsoft Access app :

```
TRANSFORM First(QueryFeatureLicenses.FeatureExists) AS PremierDeFeatureExists
SELECT QueryFeatureLicenses.Index AS [Index]
FROM QueryFeatureLicenses
GROUP BY QueryFeatureLicenses.Index
PIVOT QueryFeatureLicenses.FeatureType;
```

And it works like a charm.

But how should I convert this query with the SQL syntax? So far' I've done this :

```
SELECT BR, EI, RD, SEI, SNI, SSI
FROM
(
    SELECT FeatureType, FeatureExists
    FROM QueryFeatureLicenses
) AS d
PIVOT
(
    max(FeatureExists)
    FOR FeatureType IN (BR,EI,RD, SEI,SNI,SSI)
) AS piv;
```

But I always get the following message :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PIVOT
>       (
>           max(FeatureExists)
>           FOR FeatureType IN (BR,EI,RD, SEI,SN' at line 7

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PIVOT` is not available in MySQL. As an alternative, you can use *conditional aggregation* for this:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN FeatureType = 'BR' THEN FeatureExists END) AS BR
       MAX(CASE WHEN FeatureType = 'EI' THEN FeatureExists END) AS EI,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FeatureType = 'RD' THEN FeatureExists END) AS RD,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FeatureType = 'SEI' THEN FeatureExists END) AS SEI,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FeatureType = 'SNI' THEN FeatureExists END) AS SNI,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FeatureType = 'SSI' THEN FeatureExists END) AS SSI
FROM QueryFeatureLicenses
GROUP BY Index
```